# Extract http-equiv content with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract all **meta http-equiv** properties from url.
Here is the code

```
    function fetch_http_equiv($url)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $metas = $xpath->query('//*/meta[starts-with(@http-equiv)]');

    $http_equiv = array();

    foreach($metas as $meta){

        $property = $meta->getAttribute('http-equiv');

        $content = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        $http_equiv[$property] = $content;
    }

    return $http_equiv;
}

// fetch meta http-equiv 's

        $http_equiv = fetch_http_equiv($link);

        // if $http_equiv Content-Language exists
        if (empty($http_equiv['Content-Language'])) {
        }else{
        $meta_content_language = $http_equiv['Content-Language'];
        }
```

For the love of god In my mind it should work, what did I missed ?

edit:
I found a problem; I did changed

```
$property = $meta->getAttribute('http_equiv');
```

to

```
$property = $meta->getAttribute('http-equiv');
```

case solved.

Comment: For the love of god In your mind, what is the error ?

Comment: I've got non errors whatsoever

Comment: Then, what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: It's just doesn't show result. I'm fetching url/html document with <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pl" /> in header, it's just not working. I just  assumed that I messed up the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem; I did changed

```
$property = $meta->getAttribute('http_equiv');
```

to

```
$property = $meta->getAttribute('http-equiv');
```

case solved.

Code works now.